# Renaming of linear list directory

Tags: operating-systems, filesystems

> Consider a linear list-based directory implementation in a file system. Each directory is a list of nodes, where each node contains the file name along with the file metadata, such as the list of pointers to the data blocks. Consider a given directory foo.
>
> Which of the following operations will necessarily require a full scan of foo for successful completion?
>
> A. Creation of a new file in foo
>
> B. Deletion of an existing file from foo
>
> C. Renaming of an existing file in foo
>
> D. Opening of an existing file in foo

Here I know that the creation of a new file necessarily required a full scan. But I'm confused with how the renaming of the file necessarily requires a full scan. Please, explain how the renaming is done in the directory structure.

Comment: What if you rename it to an existing name?

Comment: Try to write out an algorithm for renaming a file.